# Eclipse ANT start commit-Dialog for SVN

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, ant, commit

I want to open the standard commit dialog for SVN in eclipse (Subclipse) with an ant-file. I found a solution to commit all changes in project but i want to decide which changes should be committed.

I hope somebody can help me :)